# Powershell command fails with "Invalid namespace" only when running as script, not in console

Tags: powershell

The following script fails on the last line with `Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace`:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $password )
Write-Host "Entering PS Session..."
Enter-PSSession -Computer hyperVServer -Credential $cred
Start-Sleep -s 5
$server = "servername"

$query = "SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName='" + $server + "'"
$VM = get-wmiobject -query $query -namespace "root\virtualization" -computername "."
```

However, when I enter this one-by-one into the console, it runs without issue.

I've added the `Start-Sleep` due to some timing issues... the session takes a few seconds to actually open. Any ideas why that line would fail only when this is running as a script?

Comment: What happens if you replace -computername "." with the actual hostname?  How is the script being called?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Interesting... now I get `Get-WmiObject : Access is denied`. If I do that `get-wmiobject` call from my local computer, I get the same issue. So I guess that even though I've entered the session on the remote computer, the script stays in the scope of the local machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter-PSSession is intended only for interactive use. If you want to run commands on a remote system in a script (non-interactively), you'll need to use Invoke-Command instead. Please run `Get-Help Invoke-Command -Full` for more details.

Comment: What he said. You'll also need to read up on how to pass local params into the remote session, which is super-easy in V3 and a bit of a hassle (but still not hard) in V2.